# Table with multiple rows and columns, column issue

Tags: tables

I am trying to replicate the following table in LaTeX[image: Table 1]

I have tried the following but I'm a beginner in making these more complicated tables, so I got stuck:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\label{tab:table2}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.0,
              table-space-text-post={*}]
            *{11}{>{$}c<{$}}
            }
\toprule
{\multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Basic Variable}}}
& \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Eq.}} 
    & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Coefficient of:}}
    & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Right Side}}
    & \multirow{4.5}{*}{\textbf{Ratio}}    \\
\cmidrule{3-8}
    &  Z     & x_1      & x_2    & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6      \\
\midrule
Z   & (0) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1    \\
\midrule
x_2   & (1) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1   \\
x_6 & (2) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1   \\
x_3  & (3) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

What can I do to fix the table? Any general suggestions are also appreciated.

Note: I do not want all vertical lines in the original table, plus the variables should be neat (not just x2, x6, x3 but with subscripts) (these things are already implemented in my code though).

Comment: You must not use `_` if you are not in math mode

Comment: Your table has a lot of different numbers of columns, that cannot work. You tell that the table should have 12 columns, second row has 8 columns, 3rd row has 10 columns. The math does not match....

Comment: If you are using Excel I suggest using excel2latex.

Comment: @DũngVũ Noooooooooo, the output of `excel2latex` adds tons of incorrect multicolumns which will totally disable the purpose of siunitx to align the numbers

Comment: @Book I fixed the first thing you mention. I see that the math does not match, but how to get it all right is hard. And no, I don't use Excel.

Comment: @Anna First count how many columns there are in your table, then make sure that each row has exactly this number of entries

Comment: @Book That's the problem. I obviously know how I want to have it (number of columns, rows), but not how to adapt my code to reach it. This is the first time I use these packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very clear what you want to achieve.

If this doesn't fit your needs, let me know.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{\label{tab:table2}A caption}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{
            *{11}{>{$}c<{$}}
            }
\toprule
\textbf{Basic}
& 
    & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Coefficient of:}}
    & \textbf{Right}     \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-9}
\textbf{Variable} &\textbf{Eq.} & Z     & x_1      & x_2    & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &\textbf{Side} \\
\midrule
Z   & (0) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1    \\
\midrule
x_2   & (1) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1   \\
x_6 & (2) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1   \\
x_3  & (3) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I recommend adding a picture showing the table.

Comment: your answer perfectly fit my taste at table design (+1)  :-)

Comment: Hi all, that's exactly what I wanted to achieve but could not. Thank you. (Another table I had to make later on I could do on my own due to the help you provided) 
And @Zarko, thanks again for your earlier suggestion for this nice table design.